# unable to validate identity server token in dotntecore web

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I have a application which is like Microsoft default templates of Asp.netCoreWebApplication->ASP.netCoreWithReact.js.

In this react client will be wrapped inside a.netcore project. All of the UI pages will be served from React. .Net core backend will be used only for APIs.

Now I have implemented IdentityServer4 and able to generate token at this end point,
http://localhost:60739/token

From react client, on login button click I could make API call to http://localhost:60739/token and could generate token using granttype password flow. but i could not validate authroize my api end points with that token

below is my client definition with in identity server solution,

```
  new Client
           {
             ClientName = "Resource Owner Flow",
             ClientId = "resource_owner_flow",
             AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
             ClientSecrets =
             {
               new Secret("resource_owner_flow_secret".Sha256())
             },
             AllowedScopes =
             {
               IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
               IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess
             },
             AllowOfflineAccess = true,
             RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
             //AccessTokenLifetime = 60,
             RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
             AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 300
           }
```

below is piece of code i am using to refer identity server,

```
 services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:60739";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateTokenReplay = false;
            options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
        });
```

I could not successfully access protected api resources? Any idea ?

If i Call http://localhost:57102/api/Home/GetSomeProtectedData using token in header i get 500 internal server error. If i remove authorize attribute on protected resource it's working fine.

below is postman screenshot,

[image]

for token creation below is the log,

IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator: Information: Token request validation success,

```
 {
   "ClientId": "resource_owner",
   "ClientName": "Resource Owner",
   "GrantType": "password",
   "Scopes": "openid",
   "AuthorizationCode": "********",
   "RefreshToken": "********",
   "UserName": "superadmin@gmail.com",
   "Raw": {
      "username": "superadmin@gmail.com",
      "password": "***REDACTED***",
      "grant_type": "password",
      "scope": "openid",
      "response_type": "token"
   }
```

}

but when I request protected API resource with token in header i get 500 internal server error and logs got created.

Comment: Identity logs when something goes wrong. Could you provide logs?

Comment: Hi @MistGun where i can see those logs?

Comment: For token generation it is adding some logs but ntng is logging when i request some api reosurce.

Comment: @Mahesh For test purposes add IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true line of code into your ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs, start project and look at Output console inside visual studio and there you'll be able to read logs for that specific request/exception.
Share this with us and we could help you :)

Comment: Hi @krazors. When i request token creation from identity server end point i could see above logs got genearted. But when i request protected api resource from api end point with token in header i imply get 500 internal server and no logs got created. let me know if there is any way to even debug and find

Comment: i feel like identity server is working fine because token is generated successfully. problem seems to be the way I refer identity server in webapp. feels like as i get 500 interval server on client web app i think my configuration to point identity server is invalid

Comment: But not getting how i can validate and fix it

Comment: What does the log from the API say?  can you add your Configure method in your API Startup  class?

Comment: 2nd code snippet in my question which says services.addauthentication is from api/.netcore web project itself. It did not add any logs

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 500 error, the problem is not the authorization flow. Else it would be 401.

You need to check out what is the real error. It can be a parsing error. You simpyly cannot finish the process because of an server side error. Please share more info, may be logs so I update the answer.

Comment: Yes if my token is invalid it would be 401. But in my client if I don't properly refer the identity server(server authority using add Authentication piece of code) then this is coming I think. But not sure how I can refer identity server end point from my app in startup. As resource itself not found or configuration invalid I am getting 500 error and no logs are generated when I request protected API resource. The logs generated at token creation I already kept in the question

Comment: If I remove Authorize attribute by on protected API resource controller I could get the data